# Looping through code stripping out unwanted tags

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-ui-sortable

i am trying to loop through my code and strip the ul and li tags out. I have managed to do this on the top layer code but once i start nesting my ul tags i am not so lucky. I have added my code below, any feedback would be brilliant.

```
<div id="sortable1">
<li class="drag"> 
   <header>header</header>
    <ul id="innerul">
        <li class="drag inner"> 
            <aside>aside</aside>
        </li> 
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="drag">
    <footer>footer</footer>
</li>
</div>
<a href="#" class="but">code</a>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
var str = '';
var a = [];
$( "#sortable1" ).sortable();
$('.but').click(function(){
    str = $('#sortable1').children('li').each(function(){            
         a.push($(this).html());
    });
    $('.box').text(a);
});

});
```

The following is printed in my div.

```
<header> header </header> <ul id="innerul"> <li class="drag"> <aside> aside </aside> </li> </ul> , <footer> footer </footer>
```

I no the jQuery is coded wrong however i just don't know how to fix this issue.

Here is the jsfiddle too.http://jsfiddle.net/P2tkp/6/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, to start with, your initial HTML is invalid, so there's no telling what the browser will do with it when building the DOM. `li` elements cannot be direct children of `div` elements. So step 1 is to start with valid HTML so you have a reliable DOM structure cross-browser.

Comment: *"i am trying to loop through my code and strip the ul and li tags out."* Just strip them out? Remove them but not their contents? What would your desired end result look like?